# Is it good practice to create a Model and ViewModel just for UI variables in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In WPF, I am currently creating a UI that requires the storage of multiple variables. I figured that the best way to do this was to create a separate model that purely stores the variables used by the view. For example, this would be the model:

```csharp
public class MainWindowModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainWindowModel()
    {

    }

    private int _currentPage;

    public int currentPage
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentPage;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentPage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("currentPage");
        }

        // below will be more properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Call it a view model...

Comment: Now I'm confused. This model is purely for data storage. If I am not mistaken, the model purely stores information and the viewmodel does all the fancy work. Sorry for any mistakes, as I'm quite new to this whole MVVM business.

Comment: A model that holds the state of the view? Or what do you mean by "UI variables"?

Comment: For example, I have an application with multiple pages, and I would want to store the current page the application is on for later use.

Comment: @CAG2: That is a ViewModel operation, area Pagination.

Comment: If you are referring to persisting the current application state, look into [Application Settings and User Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not create a ViewModel, you are not doing MVVM. ViewModel is 2 of the 4 letters, ti is very integral.

As for the Model: Creating it can be beneficial, but is not strictly nessesary.

MVVM is in large parts is about the Abitrarines of the View. And alternate views can include stuff like ASP.Net Pages, Console Applicaitons or Game/CAD like drawing. Those would not benefit from this flavor of Change Notification that is part of the ViewModel. Change Notificaiton could be a waste of CPU time with something that is prone to just redraw from scratch anyway.

But mostly the Model part is for pre-MVVM code you already have, can not change without breaking or not change enough (from Fields to Properties with Change Notificaiton). And even what I just mentioned, might just fall into [unessesary Micro Optimisations](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). So in 99% of the cases, you can just skip it. A Model is something you either have already or do not need to bother creating.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I would like to add that one if my friends who also codes makes a model for every view. Is this the best practice?

Comment: @CAG2 As I said, making a ViewModel is Mandatory. And you propably need a View jsut to debug the ViewModel too. But the Mmodel itself is largely Optional. It is something you often have. But if you lack it, you do not need to create it nessesarily.